# Angular: Hide Child Component of Dynamically Created Parent

Tags: angular

I'm working on a POC for an application where I'm just adding and removing rows for a section of the page.  Pretty standard layout:

```
<div [formGroup]="item" *ngFor="let itemof itemArray.controls; let i = index; let isLast = last">
   <input formControlName="itemNumber" />
   <kendo-switch (valueChange)='onToggle($event);'></kendo-switch>
   <child-component [hidden]="hideChild"></child-component>
</div>
```

On the back end:

```
hideItem= true;

newItem(): FormGroup {
   return this.fb.group({
      itemNumber: new FormControl(null)
   });
}

addNewItem() {
  this.itemArray.push(this.newItem());
}

onToggle(isEnabled: boolean) {
  this.hideItem= !isEnabled;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to toggle the visibility of the child component, it toggles for the child for each item, and not just the row I am on.  Trying to figure out how to have it only hit the specific child for that row.

Comment: Well, `hideChild` is the same for every `item of itemArray.controls`, so you'll have to include additional info to be able to hide one specific child. You could - for example - use the index variable of `*ngFor`.

Comment: disable/enable the formcontrol when toglling and define the visibility based on enabled state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold a state for each control of your `itemArray.controls`. I suggest you change your hideChild property.

Template :

```
<div [formGroup]="item" *ngFor="let itemof itemArray.controls; let i = index; let isLast = last">
   <input formControlName="itemNumber" />
   <kendo-switch (valueChange)='onToggle($event, i);'></kendo-switch>
   <child-component [hidden]="hideChild[i]"></child-component>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
hideChild: Record<number, boolean> = {};

newItem(): FormGroup {
   return this.fb.group({
      itemNumber: new FormControl(null)
   });
}

addNewItem() {
  this.itemArray.push(this.newItem());
}

onToggle(isEnabled: boolean, i: number) {
  this.hideChild[i]= !isEnabled;
}
```

Comment: this got me where I needed to be, thank you.